# Thunderbolt 3 on System76's Oryx Pro (oryp3) with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, hardware, multi-monitor

I got a 15" oryp3 back in 2017, and back that time I didn't realise that only 17" model had Thunderbolt 3 enabled. Before I only used one external monitor through HDMI. But recently I bought a second one and a docking station, and tried to connect via USB type-c. Clearly, it is not working for the dual monitor output. However, when the laptop and the docking station is connected, the system shows that

```
~$ lspci | grep -i thunder
02:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] (rev 02)
03:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] (rev 02)
03:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] (rev 02)
03:02.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] (rev 02)
03:04.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] (rev 02)
38:00.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 USB Controller (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] (rev 02)

~$ lspci -tv
-[0000:00]-+-00.0  Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
           +-01.0-[01]--+-00.0  NVIDIA Corporation GP106BM [GeForce GTX 1060 Mobile 6GB]
           |            \-00.1  NVIDIA Corporation GP106 High Definition Audio Controller
           +-14.0  Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
           +-14.2  Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Thermal Subsystem
           +-16.0  Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1
           +-17.0  Intel Corporation HM170/QM170 Chipset SATA Controller [AHCI Mode]
           +-1c.0-[02-6c]----00.0-[03-6c]--+-00.0-[04]--
           |                               +-01.0-[05-37]--
           |                               +-02.0-[38]----00.0  Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 USB Controller (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016]
           |                               \-04.0-[39-6c]--
           +-1c.4-[6d]--+-00.0  Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8411B PCI Express Card Reader
           |            \-00.1  Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
           +-1c.6-[6e]----00.0  Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275
           +-1d.0-[6f]----00.0  Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM961/PM961
           +-1f.0  Intel Corporation HM175 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller
           +-1f.2  Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Power Management Controller
           +-1f.3  Intel Corporation CM238 HD Audio Controller
           \-1f.4  Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family SMBus
```

It appears that Thunderbolt 3 is available but disabled. Is it correct or does it mean something else? I cannot find Thunderbolt settings anywhere in BIOS.

If it is just being disabled, is there anyway that I can enable it?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a Thunderbolt you will need to change the settings in the BIOS from `DDI to mDP` to `DDI to TBT`. You can do this by rebooting and holding the <kbd>F2</kbd> key, then go to the "Advanced" tab and choose "Advanced Chipset". Then go to the "Exit" tab to save changes and exit.

See also "Advanced BIOS menu - to switch graphical output between the DP (DisplayPort) and TBT (Thunderbolt Port)" on a different thread.

Found this on Reddit - I want to get a docking station, and saw your posts.  I figured it might help.  Let me know if it works.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. If you state "on a different thread", would you mind editing your post to add a link to that thread (see [the editing help](https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help) on how to do that).